# Adobe Reader (acroread) 64 bit looks bad

Tags: 64-bit, appearance, adobe-reader

I installed acroread on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with gdebi (also tried dpkg and via repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"). The result looks bad. For example the open-dialog is out of place, the folder-icons are green and the buttons are not rounded. Actually when I start acroread from the command-line, I get several messages and warnings:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

I remember, that I had this problem, whenever I used a 64bit-Ubuntu (even Ubuntu 12.04), but not when I used a 32bit-Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Seems the same issue as with Skype. See [Fix Skypes Theme in 64 Bit](http://smashingweb.info/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-for-perfect-desktop/).

> Skype Uses Clearlooks theme in 64 Bit Ubuntu instead of the selected system theme. Skype is a 32 Bit application and the GTK2 theme engines are installed for 64bit not for 32 Bit application. That is why Skype looks ugly in 64 Bit Ubuntu.
>   To fix this, you need to install the 32bit Murrine and Pixmap GTK2 engines. Run the commands given below.

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
```

Fixed the problem for me (14.04, 64 bit)

Answer (score 3):

We used ldap accounts with sssd daemon.

I encountered a problem with launching acroread from ubuntu 14.04 x86_64.

It did not report anything except exit code 1.

After that I used strace, and found that acroread tried to load x86 library of libnss_sss.

To resolve issue, install appropriate package:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-sss:i386
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall it and download and install it from the [official website](http://get.adobe.com/ro/reader/download/?installer=Reader_9.5.5_English_for_Linux_%28.deb%29&standalone=1) . It just works for my Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit system.But really the Adobe reader for linux is kinda old.... I say to simply use Document Viewer or Okular.

Comment: I used gdebi with AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb from the offical website. Unfortunately I need acroread sometimes where evince fails. Daniel, don't you have this kind of warnings and error-messages when you start acroread from command-line?

Comment: Sorry for late response, yes i did have a  warning on installation via Software Center but i just ignored it because as I was saying the software is old.I don't know what to say... if you want to try to go again to the official website and download not the (.deb) but the (.tar.gz) and you get a (.bin) file. You can try that one.Let me know if that works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree unless you really need Adobe reader for some reason, Okular is a much better solution. It is a lot faster and has annotations for free!

Comment: Please do not re-iterate already given answers unless you have something to add to the solution or a new perspective on the approach to the problem. If you think the answer was particularly helpful then up-vote it.